# jQuery - How to move some tag element with text inside to closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML structure:

```
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">1</i>
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">2</i>
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">3</i>
</span>
```

Now I want to move `<i>..</i>` tag with value inside `<div>..</div>` tag like:

```
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
        <i class="">1</i>
    </div>    
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
        <i class="">2</i>
    </div>    
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio" data-cid="5" data-uid="10" data-sid="1" data-pid="1" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
        <i class="">3</i>
    </div>
</span>
```

I have tried with jQuery like:

```
$('.green_box i').appendTo('.green_box div');
```

but not working. Any idea how to move `<i>..</i>` tag with closest `<div>..</div>` element.

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47htz1yb/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `each()` method to do this work.

```js
$(".green_box").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".icheckbox_flat-red_green").append($(this).find("i"));
});
```

```css
.icheckbox_flat-red_green > i {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">1</i>
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">2</i>
</span>
<span class="green_box">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-red_green">
        <input type="radio" name="minimal-radio">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
    </div>
    <i class="">3</i>
</span>
```

Using above CSS, every `i` element in `icheckbox_flat-red_green` class get `red` color.

Comment: +one for using "each" instead of "for",because i used "for" :D

Comment: Thanks. Working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/47htz1yb/3/

```
$('.green_box i').each(function(index, icon) {
    $(icon).siblings('div').append(icon)
})
```

Problem with `$('.green_box i').appendTo('.green_box div');` is that it will basically take all the `i` elements and put it in the first `.green_box div`.

What you need is to cycle through all the `i` elements, find sibling `div` and append the `i` there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.green_box i').each(function(){ 
    var $this = $(this),
        $prev = $this.prev(),
        $i = $this.remove();

    $prev.append($i);
});
```

Comment: You trying to store element in variable then removing itself. While you can cutting element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.green_box i').each(function (i) {
    $('.green_box div').eq(i).append($(this));
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!